# Dynamic space filling in the report

Tags: charts, jasper-reports

In Jasper reports, I am using JRCollections as a data source to generate the PDF.

**Problem Explanation**

I want four pie charts to be printed (one below the other) in the PDF.

**Chart-1**

**Chart-2**

**Chart-3**

**Chart-4**

If the data is not available for **chart-3** I want to print **Chart-1, Chart-2, Chart-4(one below the other)** without leaving the blank space for **chart-3.**

I tried using `<PrintWhenExpression>` on some condition but it leaves the blank space if the condition is true.

how to solve the problem without leaving the blank space for chart-3?

Comment: Did you try to play with *positionType*?

Comment: no, it's not working.I have set the PositionType=Float for the chart element.